# Git clone over SSH isn't working during docker image build for non-root user

Tags: linux, git, docker, ssh

My docker host is Debian 12.2. I can clone a private git repository over SSH in the host. I'm trying to do the same during a docker image build process. I'm forwarding my host's SSH agent during docker build. It's working when the `root` user is active during the build process, but doesn't work when the user is **non-root**. I need the process to work for **non-root** user for the purpose of the project I'm working on. Any help is appreciated.

The Dockerfile is as follows. This is a much simpler form of the whole Dockerfile used in my project to illustrate the problem.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS final-build
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Required definitions to build the image
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install required software
RUN apt update && apt upgrade && apt install -y git

# Add & switch user
ARG USER
ARG UID
ARG GID
ARG PW=a
RUN useradd -m ${USER} --uid=${UID}
RUN echo "${USER}:${PW}" | chpasswd
# USER ${UID}:${GID}

ARG GIT_SERVER
ARG PROJECT

# Create the SSH directory and set permission
# Add repo to the list of known hosts for ssh
RUN mkdir -p ${HOME}/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan ${GIT_SERVER} >> ${HOME}/.ssh/known_hosts

ARG REPO=git@${GIT_SERVER}:<snip>
ARG BRANCH

WORKDIR ${HOME}/src

# Download project source code
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone --branch ${BRANCH} --single-branch \
    ${REPO} ${PROJECT}
```

The docker image build process is as follows:

```
target="final-build"
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add

options="-f Dockerfile \
    --build-arg GIT_SERVER=${GIT_SERVER} \
    --build-arg PROJECT=${PROJECT} \
    --build-arg BRANCH=${BRANCH} \
    --build-arg USER=${USER} --build-arg UID=$(id -u) \
    --build-arg GID=$(id -u) \
    --ssh default -t test --progress=auto"

# Build the docker image
docker buildx build --target=${target} ${options} .
```

The environment variables are loaded correctly as the repository is cloned properly with the above `Dockerfile`. However, if I uncomment this line:

```
USER ${UID}:${GID}
```

in the `Dockerfile` and try to build the image, I get the following error:

```
=> ERROR [final-build 8/8] RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone --branch main --single-branch     git@  0.3s
------                                                                                                  
 > [final-build 8/8] RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone --branch main --single-branch     git@<snip> <snip>:
0.174 Cloning into '<snip>'...
0.273 Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '<snip>' to the list of known hosts.
0.326 git@<snip>: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
0.326 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
0.326 
0.326 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
0.326 and the repository exists.
------
Dockerfile:35
--------------------
  34 |     # Download project source code
  35 | >>> RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone --branch ${BRANCH} --single-branch \
  36 | >>>     ${REPO} ${PROJECT}
  37 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c git clone --branch ${BRANCH} --single-branch     ${REPO} ${PROJECT}" did not complete successfully: exit code: 128
```

Clearly, as soon as **non-root** user is switched to, the SSH agent which was forward become unavailable.

How to make it work for **non-root** user?

P.S.: I'd like to avoid copying SSH keys to the image due to the keys being available inside the image.

Comment: Where does the Dockerfile itself live?  Can you check it into the repository itself; then `git clone` the repository on the host, and `docker build` the image based on what's checked in?  This has a couple of advantages, like being able to easily build branches and other code that's not checked in yet for testing.  I'd delete pretty much everything you show in the Dockerfile so far.

Comment: @DavidMaze: The Dockerfile is on the host system. This is a much simpler form of the whole Dockerfile to illustrate the problem. In the same directory there's a build script that builds the docker image based on the Dockerfile. The image build code I've mentioned above is part of the build script. The idea is to clone the repository, then build the project inside the image and extract the output by running the image in a docker container. Everything has to be done inside the [build] container, to separate the building of the project being checked out.

Comment: Note that `ssh-keyscan` is not a secure way to get the keys for an SSH server.  It tells you what the keys are when you connect to the host now, which could be during a MITM attack.  You need to use a secure source for them, which could be hard-coding the correct keys in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Do you need to add `--ssh` like `docker buildx build --ssh default=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK `...
and `ssh-add your-private-key`

Comment: @bk2204: I understand that now. Haven't thought this way. However, I shouldn't hard code the keys in the Dockerfile for the project purpose.

Comment: @Philippe: I've just tried `--ssh default=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, it doesn't solve the problem. Calling `ssh-add` without any parameters adds all keys to the SSH agent. This works fine when using root user inside the build container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh,required=true,uid=${UID},gid=${GID} \
    git clone --branch ${BRANCH} --single-branch \
    ${REPO} ${PROJECT}
```

`--mount=type=ssh` accepts `uid` and `gid` which can be used to represent a user.